# Sorting the date in ascending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in which date is in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, and I am looking to sort this. So, I used

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AudiEvent.EventDate,'%d-%m-20%y') as Event_Date
from AudiEvent
ORDER BY Event_Date
```

Actual Output -

```
Event_Date
06-12-2013
09-11-2013
18-12-2013
26-11-2013
```

Expected Output -

```
Event_Date
09-11-2013
26-11-2013
06-12-2013
18-12-2013
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `AudiEvent` before EventDate

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AudiEvent.EventDate,'%d-%m-20%y') as Event_Date
    from AudiEvent
    ORDER BY AudiEvent.EventDate
```

Comment: it was by mistake thanx @Girish

Answer (score 3):

Please use `AudiEvent.EventDate` date field in sorting

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AudiEvent.EventDate,'%d-%m-20%y') as Event_Date
    from AudiEvent
    ORDER BY AudiEvent.EventDate
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(AudiEvent.EventDate,'%d-%m-20%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(AudiEvent.EventDate,'%d-%m-20%y') as Event_Date
from AudiEvent
order by  DATE_FORMAT(AudiEvent.EventDate,'%d-%m-20%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AudiEvent.EventDate,'%d-%m-20%y') as Event_Date
from AudiEvent
ORDER BY AudiEvent.EventDate ASC
```